# AUTOFILL IN EXCEL MACRO

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use macro recorder in Excel to record a macro to fill down a column of cells, however because the fill down each time is a different number of cells it either fills down to short or too long and this seems to be because the macro identifies the cell range and its fixed.

What I need is to auto populate or auto fill down from:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],"" "",RC[2])"
Range("C1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A261")
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A261").Select
```

Since file is not always 261? How can I place a command to choose/autofill the last column?

> Blockquote

```
Sub WMEHOT_Cleaner()
'
' WMEHOT_Cleaner Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("B:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],"" "",RC[2])"
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A261")
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A261").Select
    Range("C1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("D:E").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[2],"" "",RC[6])"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[5],""_"",RC[6])"
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A261")
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A261").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("I:J").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("E:E").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("J:J").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""WMEOnline_""&RC[9]"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A261")
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A261").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range("O5").Select




        Cells.Select
    Range("A1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    msgclean = MsgBox("Cleaning and Sorting Complete!!" & vbNewLine & "File Ready for LMS." & vbNewLine & "Please SAVE this file as CSV Format", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "WME HOT Cleaner Template")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],"" "",RC[2])"
```

Replace A if your column is not column A

Comment: I've tried this code yet nothing happened? Maybe I've just put the codes incorrectly?

Comment: What are the positions of your columns? In which column do you want the autofill formula, and which columns are you trying to concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

to find the last row from a column or

```
Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet)
i = wks.Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
j = wks.Cells.End(xlToRight).Column
```

to find the position of the last cell.

Comment: how to execute this? I mean, where will i insert those codes?

Comment: Well, in your sub I guess. You just have to replace A261 with Range("A1:A" & lr) and declare lr as integer.